# What might a C compiler produce with this statement?

Tags: c

```
a = (b - c) + (c + d) - (a + 4)
```

Can someone help me with this question? How it will look in c compiler. As I have no knowledge of C can someone tell me how this problem is solved and how it will look in assembly language?

Comment: It may produce any code that does what that statement says, or even simplify, or dismiss it, depending on the context. There’s no single compiler, no single assembly language etc so please explain what specifically is the question here

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

There is a neat site called [goldbolt.org](https://www.godbolt.org) that lets you see the wonders of compiler work.

You can play with the optimization command see [godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/dRdLGB)

Let us focus on the -O2, the compiler produces this code

```
function:                               # @function
        mov     eax, -4
        sub     eax, edi
        add     eax, esi
        add     eax, ecx
        ret
```

`a` is really in `edi`, `b` in `esi` , c in `edx` and d in `ecx`.

as you can see the compiler does

```
eax = -4
eax = eax - edi
eax = eax + esi
eax = eax + ecx
```

so basically he returns :

```
-4-a+b+d
```

which is a simplification of your formula.

You can notice that with no optimization (-O0) the compiler also does the simplification, the code is just a little bit more complex because the compiler does not do the hypothesis that `edi, esi, edx, ecx` will not change during the function call so he stores then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac computer and have Xcode installed, you can use this command in the terminal where you file object file is located

```
otool -tV <file>
```